# Card Stacks Functions is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am new to JavaScript. I don't  know  why my code does not work. I am creating functions for returning card stacks quantity. The user will input the card stack quantity. Then the card stacks will be remixed with the following rules. But the result does not appear. Can you please help debugging this code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Functions</h1>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var reposition = [];
function Reverse(userinput){
var array = new Array(userinput);
var trueform = new Array(userinput);

for(var i=0; i<userinput; i++){
   array[i] = i + 1;
   trueform[i] = i + 1;
}

while(! (isEqual(trueform,reposition))){
 for(var ii=0; ii<userinput; ii++){
  reposition[userinput-ii-1] = array[ii];
  if((ii+1) != userinput){
   swap((ii+1));
  }
 }
 for(var iii=0; iii<reposition.length; iii++){
  array[iii] = reposition[iii];
 }
 count +=1;
}
return count;
}

function swap(n){
 var temp = array[n];
 for(var iiii=n; iiii<array.length-1; iiii++){
  array[iiii] = array[iiii+1];
 }
 array[array.length-1]= temp; 
}

function isEqual(t, r){
  for(var iiiii=0; iiiii<t.length; iiiii++){
   if(t[iiiii] != r[iiiii]){
    return false;
   }
  }
  return true;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Reverse(4);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I notice is the variable array is not defined. This is because you are trying to use it in separate functions.

`this.array instead of var array`

The second thing I notice is that in your while loop you are doing count += 1 which is also not defined anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend starting with a debugger of some sort so you can even find out what errors you are getting.  If you're using Chrome, you can open their DevTools with F12.  IE and Firefox both also have their own dev tools and I think they both also use F12 as their hotkey.

Here's a link to the instructions for the [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

Otherwise @DavidR2016 is right about some of your variables being undeclared at runtime in the swap and Reverse functions.  It's a little hard to read your code as it is pasted in the question, but when I copied to NotePad++ I was able to format and read it a little better.  You also do not need to increment the number of i's in your for loops.  You can use just one i because they are scoped to the specific loop, and that will also help with readability.